# BackgroundWorker or Task, which to implement?

Tags: c#

I am new to TPL and I was wondering when to use BackgroundWorker and when to use Task. Both do the same to me. Shall I change all my BackgroundWorkers to Tasks? Do Tasks perform better or what is all that Task standing for anyway? Does a Task.Run create a new thread? Are Tasks Ui-friendlier or so?

Comment: A BGW is slightly easier to implement, Tasks now make them obsolete. But there is no reason to replace anything in exisiting code.

Comment: That's a lot of questions. A genuine answer to these broad questions would be similarly broad. That said, it is my opinion that `BackgroundWorker` is now obsolete, as Henk says. Factoring asynchronous work to use `async`/`await` and still provide progress reports can be tricky, but IMHO it's worth it for the easier-to-read code that results. Note that the net effect is really the same; i.e. when using `async`/`await` as a BW replacement, you achieve the same result: background stuff runs in a different thread, UI stuff gets executed in the UI thread. That's the point of both.

Comment: @PeterDuniho imo, `IProgress<T>` and `Progress<t>` do not get enough exposure from Microsoft. They can make progress reporting very easy but the refactor will always be big.

Comment: Are Tasks Ui-Friendlier? Do they create own threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` has been superseded by `Tasks` and in general you should use the latter when possible.

Note that besides Tasks having more features, there are also subtle differences which may be relevant.  For instance, a `Task` may not necessarily be run on a different thread, while `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` does.

Arguably, `BackgroundWorker` is easier to use and you will still need it when developing in .NET versions prior to 4.

I wouldn't recommend refactoring your existing code, just start using Tasks in your new base. I also find Tasks easier to integrate with UIs but that may be subjective.